# Can you use the Require function in client side code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When looking this up the most common answer I get is to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Since I'm developing in a Node environment I first looked at their [Use with Node](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html) section and installed the package as outlined using `npm install requirejs` and all the files installed correctly.

The first line in their usage section shows the following line of code:
`var requirejs = require('requirejs');`

When putting in this line of code, I get the same error that I've been trying to resolve this entire time `Error: require is not defined`

I'm convinced at this point that I'm just missing something here. I though the point of `RequireJS` was to allow you to use the `require()` function locally?

I'm simply trying to include a `.js` in one of my controllers. Is there any simple or effective way of doing this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "Client side code" generally means "code in the browser"; are you talking about that, or are you talking about Node?

Comment: If you want to use requirejs in the browser, then following the instructions for using requirejs in Node isn't going to help you.

Comment: No. You'll need to use something else (Browserify, Babel, etc) to allow `require` to work as you expect in the browser. Both of those libraries will transpile (transform) the code into something that works in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). I think this is what you are looking for.

It allows you to use `require('module')` at client side, just like you do it in Nodejs code.

you can follow the below steps to use it:

1) Install [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2) Get [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) using `npm install browserify -g --save-dev`
3) Write your js using `require()` like below example

main.js

```
var $=require('jquery');
$('#test').text('browserify working');
```

index.html

```
<body>
<p id='test'></p>
<script type='text/javascript' src='bundle.js'></script>
</body>
```

4) Get `jquery` using `npm install jquery --save`
5) Compile main.js to bundle.js using `browserify main.js -o bundle.js`.Here browserify will read main.js and convert it to js code that browser can understand as browser cannot understand `require()`.In simple terms browserify translates the js file for browser.
(As you can see the script tag in index.html has used bundle.js as source instead of main.js)

6) Open index.html in browser.

**Edit**
Just so you know, Requirejs and Browserify are different things and `require()` that you use for Browserify is not Requirejs.

You can refer to the example github repo [here](https://github.com/vinitm/browserify-test)

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question, but 'how' does it allow this? What I mean by this is, is there anything extra I have to do other than just installing Browserify to get it to work? I just installed it as outlined on their website but I still get the same error. The tutorial on the first page shows them using the require() function, so I'm assuming it's supposed to just work right out of the box?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. When I reached the step for compiling main.js to bundle.js I get an error saying that it cannot find that module that I am trying to loading using 'require();' I have triple check that the path to that module is correct but it is still throwing this error...

Comment: did you do step 4 for getting jquery

Comment: Yes. Followed every instruction to the letter and step 5 is where I'm stuck now.

Comment: there was a typo. change `<script type='test/javascript'` to `<script type='text/javascript'`

Comment: Corrected that, still no luck.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'klapi.js' from 'E:\project\app\scripts'. The file 'klapi.js' is located in that directory.

Comment: try keeping all the files in the same directory first

Comment: I tried. Still getting the same error. It can't seem to find any files.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a link to github repo with the example

Comment: you try it by cloning it locally